# Determine coordinates of a point in 3d space based only on distance to other points

Tags: geometry

Trying to place points of interest on a 2D map of a 3D space.

I have a L shaped structure 40 units wide and tall to act as a "ruler", I've determined 3 points on it:
A(0,0,40) - Point on the top end of L
 
B(0,0,0) - Point in the corner of L
 
C(40,0,0) - Point on the bottom end of L
 

I'd like to find X and Y coordinates of a point D(x,y,z), unless necessary for calculations Z can be ignored since this will be a 2D map.
Lengths of lines AD, BD and CD are known:
AD = 57
 
BD = 37
 
CD = 74

Looking for a formula that I could use to calculate coordinates of a number of other points.

Comment: If you have access to a computer program I'd just find the points if intersection of the three spheres of required length because solving it otherwise might be very tedious.

Comment: @Boshu That's effectively what I'm looking to do, but I'd need to find a formula for it, actual maths would ideally be handled by something like Excel. I thought of using a free 3D graphics program like Blender to brute-force it but that's rather hard to do and doesn't seem very accurate.

Comment: Actually no, it's rather simple to evaluate even on paper because the points and the lengths are nice. Just write the equations of the spheres at A,B,C down and you'll see. If you're not done, I'll try and post an answer in a course of hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A systematic way of finding the position vector $\vec{x}$ from the distances to any two given points $\vec{a},\vec{c}$ and the origin $b$, is as follows: $$|x-a|^2=|x|^2-2a\cdot x+|a|^2,$$ $$\therefore\quad 2a\cdot x=|x|^2+|a|^2-|x-a|^2=BD^2+AB^2-AD^2=u_1,$$ $$\textrm{similarly,}\ 2c\cdot x=BD^2+CB^2-CD^2=u_2.$$ Form the matrix $A=[\vec{a}\ \vec{c}]$, then the above equations translate to $A^T \vec{x}=\vec{u}$. Since $A$ is a $3\times2$ matrix, this equation has many solutions, among which are two with the given $|x|=BD$. Note that the reflected point of $D$ in the plane $ABC$ satisfies the same equations.

For the numbers you give, \begin{align*}2\vec{a}\cdot \vec{x}&=37^2+40^2-57^2=-280,\\ 2\vec{c}\cdot \vec{x}&=37^2+40^2-74^2=-2507\end{align*} Solving $\begin{pmatrix}0&0&40\\40&0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}{x\\y\\z}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-140\\-1253.5\end{pmatrix}$ gives $z=-3.5$, $x=-31.4$; for $y$, use $x^2+y^2+z^2=37^2$ to get $y=\pm19.4$.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have 3 Unknown’s with 3 equations so what about this:

$$\overline{AD} = \sqrt{(D_1-A_1)^2+( D_2-A_2)^2+ (D_3-A_3)^2)}$$
$$\Rightarrow \overline{AD}^2 = (D_1-A_1)^2+( D_2-A_2)^2+ (D_3-A_3)^2$$

With A_1 = A_2 = 0:
$$\Rightarrow \overline{AD}^2 = (D_1)^2+( D_2)^2+ (D_3-A_3)^2\qquad (1)$$

Equivalent for B and C:
$$\Rightarrow \overline{BD}^2 = (D_1)^2+( D_2)^2+ (D_3)^2\qquad (2)$$
$$\Rightarrow \overline{CD}^2 = (D_1-C_1)^2+( D_2)^2+ (D_3)^2\qquad (3)$$

Now subtract $(1)$ from $(2)$ and solve for $D_3$
Do the same with $(3)$ and $(2)$ (which you solche for $D_1$

You get $D_3$ of you plug $D_1$ and $D_3$ into $(2)$ and solve for $D_2$

Edit: these steps only work for your example because many coordinates are 0. but it should also work and other point if you adjust the steps